# Recovering files/not booting on Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

My friend installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP Laptop, and now I can't boot windows and all my work files are gone. So

1.) How can I uninstall Ubuntu?

2.) How can I recover all my work files [my job is on the line if I can't get these files back]

3.) How can I boot Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able see the Windows files from Ubuntu file manager, backup all the files that are important for you. Then re install Windows.